# Eating non-halal

Tags: sharia, food

I'm a Muslim migrant who landed in France a decade ago.

I really did my hard to eat halal food. But, I really don't want to exclude myself
since social connections are really important in my job. So, I eat in the restaurants nearby my job with my colleague.

I ate fish almost 3 years in a row. I nearly became "sick" of it. So I decided to eat (sometimes) non-halal chicken and meat.

On top of that, in some meetings, I have no choice.

What is Islam's point of view about this kind of situation?

P.S.: I'm so sorry if it could seem as a disrespect of people who are in a need.

Answer (score 2):

In those cases, I generally just try to ask for any vegetarian option instead. Where I live at least, halal meat is very rare in restaurants (and if I need to buy groceries, it's an hour trip to nearest halal market) but usually there are non-meat dishes available.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was going to suggest, because its not a necessity to always eat meat there are other types of food as well!

Answer (score 1):

Let me reply to your question by referring to a similar inquiry. A person has inquired if is it feasible to eat non-halal meat in European countries which halal meat is not available a lot or even its price is high.
**So, let’s see the view of some Shia Marja’ al – Taqlid regarding this issue.**

> According to Grand Ayatollah Khamenei, it is not permissible.
>
> According to Grand Ayatollah Sistani, no, it is not permissible.
>
> According to Grand Ayatollah Makarem-Shirazi, it is not permissible
>   in accordance with the question, unless there is a necessity for it.

As you know, as an Islamic rule, eating haram meat is haram. So, at the Fatwa of Ayatollah Makarem-Shirazi, it has mentioned that in the case of necessity it could be permissible. So the significant issue is that we cannot consider every matter as necessity, and perhaps it could be related to some specific positions, such as there is no other way for you to provide halal food (and this is a long time that you haven’t eat anything), then you’d die if .., So in that case you can eat as much as can save you, otherwise nowadays you can provide halal anyway and rarely you’ll be at such an awful location.

---

**Reference(s):**

- [www.tebyan.net](http://www.tebyan.net/newindex.aspx?pid=238580)
- [http://islamquest.net](http://islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa1431)

Comment: I don't know why this answer was downvoted. The answer's scope might only apply to Shia sect, but it is an answer non the less. The person who downvoted it, should indicate how to make it better, or more relevant.

Comment: I appreciate you for being such fair/logic user, God bless you.

Answer (score 1):

Haram food is completely forbidden until and unless the circumstances are crucial. And by crucial, I mean that it is a matter of life and death. Social connections or being cool in someone's eye is not crucial at all.
If you can not eat fish continuously, opt for vegetarian and non-alcoholic choices. There are tons of non-Muslims out there who are sober and avoid alcohol completely. And being vegetarian is completely common too. Both of these ways of living are chosen by people not only because they simply want to, but also because of health issues. So if someone persuades you to consume the haram items,and you don't want to mention the religious restrictions, you could simply say that you are allergic to it, or have health issues related to it.

Answer (score -1):

There's no biological difference between ritual meat and normal meat. So in terms of health you won't be hurt as you would be with alcohol.

Comment: I don't think he asked about "biological difference between halal and non-halal meat"!

Comment: This not be Islam's point of view which is asked in question. Also there are health benefits of eating halal meat since it is more hygienic.